# office 365 mail app store submission issue

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-web-app

While publishing the office 365 mail app to store, I struck with the issue

**The app manifest contains a URL to an invalid icon in the IconUrl element. The icon's size is not valid. Learn more.**

I have used 64*64 , 128 * 128, 32*32 and 96*96. Nothing worked.
I'm using png image.

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Selva, could you please include the manifest you're trying to install?

Comment: I have same issue even i had added exactly  (64*64) , (128 * 128) icons